# Debugging a (marshalled) RCW proxy blocks the message loop on the COM server - why?

Tags: debugging, process, com, deadlock, rcw

I have a simple process that accesses the Excel application object. It subscribes to an event and then attaches a debugger to itself.

The entire source code of the app is as follows:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var excel = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

    // if any event has a subscription, attaching the debugger
    // freezes the message loop in Excel while the debugger is paused 
    excel.WorkbookNewChart += (a,b) => {};

    Debugger.Launch();
}
```

When the debugger (e.g. Visual Studio) starts, it freezes (all the threads in) my console app.

What I find puzzling is, this also blocks the message loop in Excel, making Excel unresponsive. However, the message loop in Excel is only blocked if I subscribe to some event, e.g. WorkbookNewChart. It doesn't matter which event and it doesn't matter if the event is fired or not.

My questions are:

- Why might attaching the debugger to this console app freeze Excel's message loop and is there something I can do prevent it?
- I'm only seeing the behavior of Excel as a black box - are there any tools I could use to figure out what might be blocking the message pump in the Excel process?

[Update: running the same three lines of code in a WPF window's `Loaded` event handler has the same outcome.]

---

**Background** - why I'm interested in this:

I'm making an IDE inside Excel which can be used to build small apps. These apps run in their own processes but access Excel via `Marshal.GetActiveObject`. My IDE is an Excel add-in running inside the Excel process. I'd like my IDE to be able to debug the runner processes that I spawn from the IDE. Things seem to work ok when starting the apps, but I get deadlocked in situations like the one above, where the debugger freezes the runner process which then blocks the excel process, which makes me unable to use the debugger.

[image: Screenshot of the debugger]

I can, of course, run my debugger/IDE in another separate process, but from a user experience perspective I'd love to keep it inside the Excel task pane if possible.

Comment: It seems like it's a Console app. You must run a message pump in a console app to make sure messages can be processed (COM apartment calls flow as window messages). You might also try with STAThread attribute on Main()

Comment: @SimonMourier it seems like it's not the cause. I put the same three lines of code in a WPF window's Loaded event handler and got the same outcome: while the debugger is paused at the Debugger.Launch() line, the Excel process is unresponsive. Same as before, Excel only gets stuck if I subscribed to any event prior to the Debugger.Launch() call.

Comment: Note sure I understand. I've tested a WPF app (not tested console), run with CTRL+F5, attached with Visual Studio 2019 (or start the debugger with F5 from Visual Studio), and Excel is blocked only when the debugger is halted in an Excel event code in the WPF app, otherwise Excel runs normally. COM is synchronous, so there is one logical thread from Excel to the app, and obviously Excel waits for the call to complete, that's how it behaves at least for this event.

Comment: @SimonMourier that's strange, it doesn't correspond to the behavior I'm seeing. I just tested again in a WPF app, in a window.Loaded event handler, I tried regular debugging (F5), after first line (GetActiveObject) Excel is responsive, but when I execute the second line (event subscription) Excel is responsive for the first click and then unresponsive until I let the debugger continue. After a minute or so, Excel pops up a message saying "Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action". If I click ok, Excel accepts one click and then freezes again.

Comment: Yes, this is what I see too, these type of events are using connection points: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/architecture-of-connectable-objects which creates bidirectional referencing. I'm not sure it's caused by the debugger or by Excel implementation, but that doesn't seem abnormal behavior to me.

Comment: @SimonMourier in my case it's undesired behavior since it means my debugger cannot be hosted inside the Excel process. I still find it puzzling, because the event I subscribed to is never fired, yet Excel still seems to be waiting for something from my runner process (the process that is being debugged). I don't know what it's waiting for and if it can be told not to. I am aware that having a debugger in the Excel process while at the same time debugging a process that is interacting with Excel is iffy, but figured I'd explore if it might be possible.

Comment: I've noticed in Visual Studio that the line that subscribes to the WorkbookNewChart event results in a new worker thread being created. I guess this thread is meant to respond to queries in the other direction (from Excel to my process) and since the debugger freezes all threads, Excel cant get a reply from that thread. If Excel could fire-and-forget when calling event handlers that might work, but I guess that's not the case so I think my debugger will have to move out of the Excel process. Thank you for your time and help with this @SimonMourier!